# Appending Columns from several worksheets Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to import certain columns of data from several different sheets inside of a workbook. However, while appending it only seems to append 'q2 survey' to a new workbook. How do I get this to append properly?

```
import sys, os
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlwt


b = ['q1 survey', 'q2 survey','q3 survey'] #Sheet Names
df_t = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Month","Date", "Year"]) #column Name
xls = "path_to_file/R.xls"
sheet=[]
df_b=pd.DataFrame()
pd.read_excel(xls,sheet)
for sheet in b:
       df=pd.read_excel(xls,sheet)
       df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().upper(), inplace=True)
       bill=df_b.append(df[df_t])


bill.to_excel('Survey.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you do:

```
b = ['q1 survey', 'q2 survey','q3 survey'] #Sheet Names
list_col = ["Month","Date", "Year"] #column Name
xls = "path_to_file/R.xls"
#create the empty df named bill to append after
bill= pd.DataFrame(columns = list_col) 
for sheet in b:
   # read the sheet
   df=pd.read_excel(xls,sheet)
   df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().upper(), inplace=True)
   # need to assign bill again
   bill=bill.append(df[list_col])
# to excel
bill.to_excel('Survey.xlsx', index=False)
```

it should work and correct the errors in your code, but you can do a bit differently using `pd.concat`:

```
list_sheet = ['q1 survey', 'q2 survey','q3 survey'] #Sheet Names
list_col = ["Month","Date", "Year"] #column Name
# read once the xls file and then access the sheet in the loop, should be faster
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile("path_to_file/R.xls")
#create a list to append the df
list_df_to_concat = []
for sheet in list_sheet :
   # read the sheet
   df= pd.read_excel(xls_file, sheet)
   df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().upper(), inplace=True)
   # append the df to the list
   list_df_to_concat.append(df[list_col])
# to excel
pd.concat(list_df_to_concat).to_excel('Survey.xlsx', index=False)
```